# QGIS 3.2 Grass processing algorithms not working

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

Update- This is an old thread and my issues have been resolved in subsequent versions. One common problem in QGIS version 3.0 to 3.18 is to make sure that you are running QGIS with Grass otherwise GRASS won't work.

Original Post:
All the Grass processing algorithms I have tried on windows 10 QGIS 3.2.1 give me the error below. Anyone else experiencing this? Any solutions?

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'v.buffer' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-c' : False, '-s' : False, '-t' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'angle' : 0, 'cats' : '', 'column' : None, 'distance' : 100, 'input' : 'G:/My Drive/GIS_DATA/Project Data/MMTC/pond.shp', 'minordistance' : None, 'output' : 'C:/Users/BAS/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_b45361d56a76487ba46a6c3186e7fd8f/5b2a3d4064364147ad44386aabf002d9/output.shp', 'scale' : 1, 'tolerance' : 0.01, 'type' : [0,1,4], 'where' : '' }

g.proj -c proj4="+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="G:\My Drive\GIS_DATA\Project Data\MMT\pond.shp" output="vector_5b78e50bc752f3" --overwrite -o
g.region n=5622558.817551329 s=5622558.817551329 e=-7832392.192254409 w=-7832392.192254409
v.buffer input=vector_5b78e50bc752f3 type="point,line,area" distance=100 angle=0 scale=1 tolerance=0.01 output=output472320f11531410082718db00660058f --overwrite
v.out.ogr -c type="auto" input="output472320f11531410082718db00660058f" output="C:\Users\BAS\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_b45361d56a76487ba46a6c3186e7fd8f\5b2a3d4064364147ad44386aabf002d9\output.shp" format="ESRI_Shapefile" --overwrite

'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.    
'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.2\apps\Python36\lib\site.py", line 177 file=sys.stderr)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Press any key to continue . . . 

'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.    
'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.2\apps\Python36\lib\site.py", line 177 file=sys.stderr)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Press any key to continue . . . 

Execution completed in 0.69 seconds
Results:
{'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':C:/Users/BAS/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_b45361d56a76487ba46a6c3186e7fd8f/5b2a3d4064364147ad44386aabf002d9/output.shp, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>C:/Users/BAS/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_b45361d56a76487ba46a6c3186e7fd8f/5b2a3d4064364147ad44386aabf002d9/output.shp</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Comment: Can you check your GRASS path under Settings -> Options -> Processing -> Providers -> GRASS -> "GRASS 7 Folder"?

Comment: It's C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.2\apps\grass\grass-7.4.1. Does that seem right? Before I reinstalled and removed my settings folder it was grass-7.4.0. Is it possible that that came through when I imported my settings from QGIS 2? The only thing I've found is something about single quotes ' vs double quotes " in the path file name.

Comment: Does "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.2\apps\grass\grass-7.4.1" exist?

Comment: "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.2\apps\grass\grass-7.4.1" does. I don't know how the "~1" part works.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can anyone tell what is the issue?

Comment: I never figured it out. If I need to use Grass I use QGIS 2.18.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add quote in "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.2\bin\grass74.bat" file
so it would be like this:

```
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-7.4.1\etc\env.bat"
```