# QGIS r.clump function not working?

Tags: qgis-3

I am trying to follow this course "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfZSyBf6o84", starting from 20:00, and failed to reproduce the clump function based file, as the warning message shows:[image]
Anyone have idea where the problem is?

The file needed for being processed can be found here:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hu7cAk2cf-EyUQdpZNX8gUmH1JnOqoBi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This reminds me another post [QGIS 3.2 Grass processing algorithms not working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293253/qgis-3-2-grass-processing-algorithms-not-working) (it was about `v.buffer`). Meanwhile I have successfully run `r.clump` with your data by QGIS 3.2.3. If you are using older QGIS sub-version, could you try updating it?

Comment: Thanks Kazuhito, I am using the latest versionof QGIS, and I checked the post you gave, and confirm that I have the correct the Grass path indicated by the answering person:C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.2\apps\grass\grass-7.4.1. No idea why the problem still exist though...